# Why does Sen. Schumer decide to vote against his cloture motion at the last minute?

Tags: united-states, senate-rules

Today, the Senate voted on cloture on a resolution related to the ratification of the Equal Rights Amendment. Two republicans senators voted Yes, but apart from that it was along party lines (with some members absent), but at the last minute, Chuck Schumer, the Majority Leader, changed his vote to No.

C-SPAN reports this was due to "procedural matters", and that it's in order to be able to call the vote again later. He had done that in the past already, on a bill related to abortion if my memory serves correctly.

What's the Senate rule regarding this ? How does the limit he's circumventing work ?