Why would voting no on legislation to allow for it to be reintroduced be beneficial?
The US Senate introduced a pair of bills which failed to get past the filibuster 60-vote threshold.
In this article and this one, it was indicated that the Senate Majority Leader, changed his vote from Yes to No and by doing so it gave him the option to bring the bill back up again in the future.
The Rules of the Senate seems to indicate that senators are called to vote in alphabetical order and cannot change their votes once made per Section XII:

When the yeas and nays are ordered, the names of Senators shall be called alphabetically; and each Senator shall, without debate, declare his assent or dissent to the question, unless excused by the Senate; and no Senator shall be permitted to vote after the decision shall have been announced by the Presiding Officer, but may for sufficient reasons, with unanimous consent, change or withdraw his vote. No motion to suspend this rule shall be in order, nor shall the Presiding Officer entertain any request to suspend it by unanimous consent.

Furthermore, under Section XIII of the rules, it appears to allow for reintroduction of a bill:

When a question has been decided by the Senate, any Senator voting with the prevailing side or who has not voted may, on the same day or on either of the next two days of actual session thereafter, move a reconsideration...

I think this means that if a Senator wants to reintroduce legislation for debate after it's been voted upon to not introduce it, they may do so, but only within 2 session days.
My questions are as follows:

Why is the Senate Majority Leader allowed to change his vote at all, it seems unlikely they would receive unanimous consent? Is this a privilege of the Majority Leader?
Am I understanding the rule correctly regarding voting No? Is a senator only allowed to reintroduce the legislation within 2 session days? If so, it doesn't seem very advantageous. Or am I misreading it and there's some loophole that allows it to be reintroduced at any time during the current session?


Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27505/26455 and https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79398/26455.

Just in case it becomes necessary, I don't think my question is a duplicate of the ones cited by @RickSmith as I'm trying to understand what the specific procedural rules are that allow for a change in vote (it's possible I'm not looking at the right ones). Also, I am trying to understand how substantial the political benefit really is, the other questions both lead to the answer of being able to bring the question up again, but it's unclear how much of a benefit that realistically is.

Any member of congress can change their vote as many times as they want as long as the vote is still open.

The Rules of the Senate seems to indicate that senators are called to vote in alphabetical order and cannot change their votes once made. Furthermore, under Section XIII of the rules, it appears to allow for reintroduction of a bill:

This is a special type of voting and normally they vote by electronic means and even with a voice vote members are still allowed to change their vote before the vote ends.
AS for the second question I think you are misunderstanding what was being voted on. The vote was to end the filibuster which is required in order for the bill itself to come up for a vote. In this case the rules say you have to be on the winning side to attempt to bring it up again.

When a question has been decided by the Senate, any Senator voting with the prevailing side or who has not voted may, on the same day or on either of the next two days of actual session thereafter, move a reconsideration; and if the Senate shall refuse to reconsider such a motion entered, or if such a motion is withdrawn by leave of the Senate, or if upon reconsideration the Senate shall affirm its first decision, no further motion to reconsider shall be in order unless by unanimous consent. Every motion to reconsider shall be decided by a majority vote, and may be laid on the table without affecting the question in reference to which the same is made, which shall be a final disposition of the motion.

They change their votes to no once it is clear that the vote to end the filibuster won't succeed so that they can attempt to bring it up again. This isn't a loophole but rather preventing someone from brining a failing motion up for vote over and over again.

I've added a quote of relevant parts of the voting rules, they don't seem to allow for changing ones vote without unanimous consent (which I doubt anyone would get). Can you expand this answer to clarify what part of the Senate's rules allow for someone to change their vote as much as they want?

I'm not sure you've really answered my second question. I understand the goal was to end the filibuster, but I'm trying to figure out how it's a benefit to be able to reintroduce the legislation later if the restriction is that it must occur within 2 session days. Is there some weird way 'session days' is defined that makes this a huge boon?

@Pyrotechnical You are talking about a single method of voting that isn't used that often and they mostly vote by electronic vote or voice vote.

That's fine, but can you point me to what Senate rules apply for the current voting scheme? If the answer is that the Senate's written rules don't actually sync up with the rules they actually use that's fine. I'm just seeing a disconnect right now and not understanding.

@Pyrotechnical you are quoting a specific rule for a specific type of voting and there are several different ways that they can vote on something.

Again, I hear what you're saying. Can you point me to what Senate rules apply for this type of voting? I was looking in the section titled Voting Procedures, but this would hardly be the first time that applicable rules are spread out in a non-intuitive way.

"Unlike the House, the Senate does not have an electronic voting system; recorded votes are conducted through a call of the roll." The Legislative Process: Senate Floor (Video). See the text at the end of the transcript.

"preventing someone from brining a failing motion up for vote over and over again." Yet it seems to fail that goal, since a loser can join the winning side and bring it back up for reconsideration.
